# Prove that if $ab=n$, then either $a\leq \sqrt{n}$ or $b\leq\sqrt{n}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that if $ab=n$, then either $a\leq \sqrt{n}$ or $b\leq \sqrt{n}$, where $a, b$ and $n$ are non-negative real numbers.  Hint: use contradiction.

I am quite stuck on how to solve this problem, I feel it is easy. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is not difficult. What have you tried so far? You are told to use contradiction. So you start by assuming that both $a$ and $b$ are $>\sqrt{n}$. What can you conclude from that?

Comment: If both $a,b$ were $> \sqrt{n}$ then what would that say about $ab$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that if $n=ab$, $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, then $a \leq \sqrt{n}$ or $b \leq \sqrt{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148509/prove-that-if-n-ab-a-and-b-are-positive-integers-then-a-leq-sqrtn)

Comment: You are right, my appoligies for not stating what I have so far.  a * b = n, then a AND b must be >= $\sqrt{n}$. That is where I am at right now.

Comment: That is false: $10=2\cdot 5$ is a counter example.

Comment: Yes I understand the counter example, but it is necessary to prove it for the general example.

Comment: @jcarls Can you answer almagest's or copper.hat's comment?

Comment: @almagest So with contradiction, a * b = n, then a AND b must be >= $\sqrt{n}$. Following, a$^2$ * b$^2$ >= n$^2$.  We square n because it gets rid of the square root.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: @Berci Please see above

Comment: @jcarls That is not quite right. If $a>\sqrt{n}$ and $b>\sqrt{n}$, then $ab>n$. Can you see the next step?

Comment: @almagest So you don't sqaure both sides?  Becuase I see that it is just n now instead of $\sqrt{n}$ and the way you did that was by $\sqrt{n}$$^2$.  I do not see the next step

Comment: @jcarls You don't square. You multiply the left sides together and the right sides together. All the numbers involved are positive, so we still get a valid inequality. If $0<u<v$ and $0<r<s$, then $ur<vs$. Yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Statement:

If $a, b, n>0$ and $ab=n$ then $a\le\sqrt n$ or $b\le\sqrt n$.

### Proof.

Proof by contradiction. We assume that the conclusion doesn't hold, i.e. neither $a$ nor $b$ are $\le\sqrt n$, that is, both $a, b>\sqrt n$.

Then we simply get
$$a\cdot b\ >\ \sqrt n\cdot\sqrt n\ =\ n$$
which is already a contradiction, as $ab=n$ was supposed.

Comment: I thought if you did something to one side of the equation, you had to do it to the other side.  So a * b > $\sqrt{n}$, would mean a$^2$ * b$^2$ = n, but now I see that a * b > n which is a contradiction since a * b = n and n > n...

Comment: This is a proof by contraposition, not by contradiction.

Comment: What we did here is to multiply two inequalities (with only positive elements occurring).

Comment: I know that, but it is not a contradiction.

Comment: So how come you can multiply $\sqrt{n}$ by $\sqrt{n}$?  I see now how it is false since n > n is false.

Comment: @Berci Please see my comment.  I am confused as to why multiply them together.  Thanks.

Comment: If we have any positive numbers $A,B,C,D$ and $A>C$ and $B>D$, then it is true that $AB>CD$ (e.g. because $AB>CB>CD$ using that we can multiply an inequality by a positive number.) Nothing else happened but it was applied with $A=a,\, B=b,\, C=D=\sqrt n$.

Comment: Thank you!!! That makes sense!! Grateful for your indepth responses!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use contrapositive: observe that if both $a^2,\:b^2<n$, then $(ab)^2<n^2$.

Comment: Right so we square them because, a$^2$ * b$^2$ = n since squaring n gets rid of the square root.  What would be after?

Comment: If you prove that $(ab)^2<n^2$, what can you conclude for $ab$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be (ab)$^2$ >= n$^2$ since we are using contradiction and it changed in the revision on the proof?

Comment: What I suggest is proceeding by contraposition (that many people think is contradiction):  to prove $p\implies q$, you prove $\neg q\implies \neg p$.